# Can't send input to running program in Sublime Text

Tags: python, input, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-build

I'm trying to get Sublime Text 3 to run a Python script. A simple two liner

```
var = raw_input("Enter something: ")
print("You entered " + var)
```

which asks for input, waits for it, then prints it out in windows console prompt.

Seeing the number of similar questions on the site, this is a problem for quite a number of users, so I went through those and tried ... stuff. Made a copy of exec.py file, commented that one line, made a new pythonw build file, tried messing about with the build file ... nothing seems to work.

In lack of a definite solution, how do you work with input using Sublime Text?

Comment: Are you trying to get your system Python to run the script, or ST3 itself?

Comment: @MattDMo - I didn't know ST3 came bundled with python. But, in any case, I'm trying to get my system python (situated in c:\python27\) to run it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Sublime Text on its own cannot handle input via `raw_input()` (Python 2) or `input()` (Python 3). The same is true of other languages as well - Ruby's `gets`, Java's `Scanner` class, Node's `readline` class, `scanf` in C, `cin` in C++, etc. One short-term solution is to get [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io) if you don't already have it, then install [SublimeREPL](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeREPL). It allows you to transfer or run part or all of your code through the running REPL. It may require some configuration of the `Main.sublime-menu` files to get your preferred interpreter to run properly. Alternatively, you can use the excellent [Terminus](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Terminus) plugin - details are at the bottom.

If the code you're running doesn't play well with SublimeREPL (for instance, you're using C/C++/Java/etc. and need to compile code before it runs), or you just want to run it independently of Sublime, you'll need to make your own [build system](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/build_systems.html). Save the following as `Packages/User/Python_cmd.sublime-build`:

### Windows

```json
{
    "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/k", "c:/python38/python.exe", "$file"],
    "selector": "source.python",
    "shell": true,
    "working_dir": "$file_dir",
    "env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
}
```

changing the path to your Python executable as appropriate. Then, go to **`Tools -> Build System`** and select `Python_cmd`, and when you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to build, a new `cmd` window will open up with your file running. The `/k` option returns to the command prompt, without closing the window, after your program is done running so you can examine output, tracebacks, etc.

Please note that this build system is Windows-specific, as macOS and Linux do not have `cmd`. Build systems for those platforms are below.

---

### macOS

If you are running OS X/macOS, the following build system will open your program in a new instance of Terminal. Save it as `Packages/User/Python_Terminal.sublime-build`. In my testing on macOS 10.15, the Terminal window didn't always come to the top when activated, so if you may need to look for it behind other windows.

```json
{
    "shell_cmd": "osascript -e 'tell app \"Terminal\" to do script \"cd $file_path && python3 -u $file\"'",
    "working_dir": "$file_path",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
}
```

You may need to specify the path to your Python executable if it's not on your `$PATH`.

---

### Linux

And finally, here is a build system for Linux. It was tested on Ubuntu, so if you use another distribution you'll need to ensure that `gnome-terminal` is installed. Save it as `Packages/User/Python_shell.sublime-build`. Once the program has finished running, hit any key to close the window.

```json
{
    "shell_cmd": "gnome-terminal --working-directory=$file_path -- bash -c 'python3 -u \"$file\" && read -n 1 -s -r'",
    "working_dir": "$file_path",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
}
```

---

For reference, the `Packages` directory is the one opened when selecting **`Preferences → Browse Packages…`**:

- Linux: `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages` or `~/.config/sublime-text/Packages`
- OS X: `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages` or `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text/Packages`
- Windows Regular Install: `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages` or `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text\Packages`
- Windows Portable Install: `InstallationFolder\Sublime Text 3\Data\Packages` `InstallationFolder\Sublime Text\Data\Packages`

<sup>The exact path depends on version and whether or not you upgraded from Sublime Text 3.</sup>

I have only tested these build systems with Python, but they should work fine for any language. When modifying, just make sure that all the single and double quotes match up – you'll get errors or unexpected behavior if they don't.

---

## UPDATE

There is a platform-independent plugin called [Terminus](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Terminus) that, among other things, provides a drop-in replacement for the default `exec` build system engine. It allows you to interact with your program in the build panel below your code. Once you've installed it from Package Control, create the following build system (again, for Python):

```json
{
    "target": "terminus_exec",
    "cancel": "terminus_cancel_build",
    "cmd": [
        "/path/to/python", "-u", "$file"
    ],
    "working_dir": "$file_path",
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
}
```

You'll need to adjust the path to your Python executable, as above. Make sure you read the documentation to find out all the other ways you can make use of this great plugin.

Comment: Hi, I recall using this solution several times before on my different Ubuntu and Linux Mint installations and it was working. However, I stopped using sublime a while ago, and I had reinstalled my Linux Mint 17.2, so I had to set this up again when I wanted to use sublime. However, I get this error: `start: missing job name
Try `start --help' for more information.` What should I do?

Comment: @Rohan as you can clearly see from the question's tags, and the path in the build system, this is a solution for Windows, not Linux.

Comment: @Rohan No. `start` and `cmd` are Windows commands - they don't exist in Linux or OS X.

Comment: this works for me perfectly. It opens the python file in command prompt as interpreter. Input is also working perfectly.

Comment: what does "You may need to specify the path to your Python executable if it's not on your $PATH" mean?

Comment: Baller write-up right there.

Answer (score 1):

To add on to the answer from [Shritam Kumar Mund](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61711734/10408367), to make a key binding for this:

> { "keys": ["alt+k", "alt+k"], "command": "repl_open", "args": {"cmd":
> ["python", "-u", "$file_basename"], "cwd": "$file_path", "encoding":
> "utf8", "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}, "external_id":
> "python", "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage", "type":
> "subprocess"}},

I found this by using the following in the console:

```
sublime.log_commands(True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text does not support inputting data into a program.  For working with inputs you need to install a package called [SublimeREPL](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeREPL).
Follow this:

1. open Sublime Text >> CTRL + P
2. CTRL + P will open the Package control
3. Click on Package Control: Install package
4. Wait for a sec to pop up a search bar.
5. Type SublimeREPL and Click it. 
   It'll get installed in a few secs.

Then follow the following steps to run your program;

6. Tools >> SublimeREPL >> Python >> Python run Current File

It'll open a new window, where you can give your input and get the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this *sublime_build* file which make run on cmd when you press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> .

Just go to **tool ->sublime build->new build system** and paste the below given as it is;

I have personally edited this sublime build file with my experience and believe me it has some good functionalities:

1. color changing when program terminates or ends
2. interactive output and input
3. console window automatic opening
4. pause after program finishes and wait till enter

```
{
"cmd":["start", "cmd", "/c" ,"python $file && color b0 && pause"],
"selector": "source.python",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"file_regex": "(.+):(\\d+): error: ",
"shell": true 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [@MattDMo for the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19297613/7266363), which doesn't require installing any plugin. But after I tried the command in macOS:

```
"shell_cmd": "osascript -e 'tell app \"Terminal\" to do script \"cd $file_path && python3 -u $file\"'",
```

I find it seems to run from background every time, which is not convenient.

So I tried another method: to use a temp.sh to run. Here is the command:

```
"cmd": ["zsh", "-c", "echo \"python3 ${file}\" > /tmp/tmp.sh ; chmod +x /tmp/tmp.sh ; open -a Terminal /tmp/tmp.sh ; sleep 2 ;rm /tmp/tmp.sh"],
```

This method will pop up a new window to the front, and it should be feasible on other platforms after a small modification, but I didn't try.

here is the full content in "python_input.sublime-build":

```
{
    "cmd": ["zsh", "-c", "echo \"python3 ${file}\" > /tmp/tmp.sh ; chmod +x /tmp/tmp.sh ; open -a Terminal /tmp/tmp.sh ; sleep 2 ;rm /tmp/tmp.sh"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"},
}
```