# NASM entering the name program never exits

Tags: ubuntu, assembly, sublimetext3, x86-64

```
section .data 
    tekst db "Unesite ime"
    ispis db "Uneseno "

section .bss
    name resb 16

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    call _ispisTekst
    call _unijetIme
    call _ispisIme

    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall

_ispisTekst:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, tekst
    mov rdx, 11
    syscall
    ret

_unijetIme:
    mov rax, 0
    mov rdi, 0
    mov rsi, name
    mov rdx, 16
    syscall
    ret

_ispisIme:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, name
    mov rdx, 16
    syscall
    ret
```

Since im new to asm programming can someone explain me and find mistake why program never exits. The program should output "enter the name" then user should enter and then program writes entered name, but after entering name it doesnt do anything. Using terminal it works but on sublime it doesnt, im using sublime 3.

Comment: What's the name of your file? How did you assemble and link it? What did you enter to execute it? Did you get an error message or truly nothing?

Comment: Works fine here.

Comment: i got nothing, after entering name it just stays no exit no error
i can enter as much as i will no changes, im using sublime 3

Comment: yes using terminal works fine but same code in sublime 3 doesnt work

Comment: Presumably it's not passing standard input to your program. Anyway, that's not a problem with your program. Maybe sublime pops up a separate terminal window that you haven't noticed or something like that? (I am not familiar with it.)

Comment: ok thank you  btw is there good ide except sasm for ubuntu ofc,

Comment: If you are looking for a development editor you could look at CodeBlocks

Comment: Try running your program under `strace` to see what system calls it makes.  See the bottom of the x86 tag wiki for debugging tips (with `strace` and `gdb`): https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info

Comment: Programs executed by Sublime don't have their standard input connected to anything, so you can't interact with them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue with Sublime Text 3's build system - can't get input from running program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254765/issue-with-sublime-text-3s-build-system-cant-get-input-from-running-program)