# Input not works

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3

I had installed the Sublime Text 3 in Python 3.6 in my windows, I created a file ".py" on sublime and then when I need to use the "input" command, it don't recognize.  I can type every time that will happens nothing, I got those problems with another IDE's.I tried copy and paste some codes which I have seen in some forums to create a modified build system to solve the problem but I don't know if I had done correctly or it don't works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue with Sublime Text 3's build system - can't get input from running program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254765/issue-with-sublime-text-3s-build-system-cant-get-input-from-running-program)

Comment: You may get more help if you include in your question what you're already trying that's not working.