# How to fix sublime text terminating after input from user?

Tags: python, sublimetext3, bots

**Question**

Hey I'm basically a noob at sublime text and just transitioned from Anaconda Spyder because I'm trying to make a bot for supreme

I'm testing stuff out and I had two input lines which looked something like input("hola") and if I type in "hi" into the console the code would stop and would not run the rest of the code and I wasn't sure why that was?

Comment: You're asking multiple, completely unrelated questions in one. Pick one and edit the question to stick to that question. Or post separate questions for your separate questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue with Sublime Text 3's build system - can't get input from running program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254765/issue-with-sublime-text-3s-build-system-cant-get-input-from-running-program)

Answer (score -1):

I would use python to make a supreme bot. I am doing kinda the same thing just wanting to make an adidas bot. I did some research and most botters use python.

If you type hi in to the debug console it will stop running but instead you should open the file and run it in terminal or command line. just write

cd /path/of/your/file

python yourfilename.py

This should make it say hola and you having the possibility of answering hi. please share some more of you program