# Gosublime doesn't accept standard input from console

Tags: sublimetext3, user-input, gosublime

I just downloaded lastest sublime yesterday, a new user to sublime. I am using gosublime:go to implement some basic command. Problem came out when I tried to run the following code:

```
    package main

    import (
    "fmt" )

    func main() {
    fmt.Print("Enter text: ")
    var input string
    fmt.Scanln(&input)
    fmt.Print(input) 
}
```

Program is supposed to wait for standard input to continue.
But actually my IDE just finished without any waiting process.

Here is the output:

[ `go run hallo.go` | done: 235.139884ms ]

```
Enter text:
```

I tried to find a solution online but it seems nobody else have the exact same issue before. Since I tried different commands and packages but none of them can let the program waiting for my input. So I consider this is the problem due to IDE rather than command.

Please tell me if you have any solution.

Go version

go version go1.10.3 darwin/amd64

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue with Sublime Text 3's build system - can't get input from running program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254765/issue-with-sublime-text-3s-build-system-cant-get-input-from-running-program)

Comment: So sublime text originally does not support standard. Is gosublime not capable of handling standard input as well?
I tried to install sublimeREPL and run under REPL just now. The issue remains there. I am not sure if I need my own build system as Mattdmo mentioned in his solution. If so, I don't know what should be in my configuration since he answered the question is python within windows system.