# Whenever i run my code the line under the input statement is never run:

Tags: python, sublimetext

I can't run any line of code that is under my input variable.

I have checked for typos but there aren't any.

```
def inputs():
    global guess, count
    count = (0)
    while len(theWord) > (count):
        for i in range(len(theWord)):
            print (theWord[i])
            print (count)
    **      guess = str(input("Guess a letter A-Z:").strip())**
    **      print ("test") <---- should run**
        if guess == theWord[i]:
        graphic[i] = (guess)
        print (graphic)
        count = count + (1) 

inputs()
```

Comment: how are executing this function? If you are not in an active shell/terminal where you can actually reply to the `input` with data, this is expected behavior.

Comment: it works for me - it display `"test"`.

Comment: I am in a sublime project. And why can I not run anything directly under an input statement in the function? Does this mean I have to end the function with an input statement?

Comment: it means that problem is Sublime, not code. Run it without Sublime.

Comment: Sublime is not a shell - so this is expected. Use CMD if you are on Windows, or Terminal on Mac and you will see the input

Comment: No, it means you have to run this script in some sort of terminal/console to be able to input the data

Comment: Thank you it worked in pycharm but why do you think it didn't work in sublime?

Comment: I have no idea why it doesn't work in Sublime. Bug or Feature.

Comment: Why do you put parenthese around variables?

Comment: @SMITHINCOMEDY it is a missing feature in sublime text, check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19297613/10146012

Comment: Use [sublime input](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Sublime%20Input)