# Basic Tax Calculator in Python 3.7.6

Tags: python

I am very new to programming and I've just been learning to write basic python using sublime text and running my code though the sublime python system build.
I am trying to write a basic VAT calculator that will take user input and add the amount of 20% on the subtotal.
Here is the code:

```
subtotal = float(input("Enter the #: "))
vat = float(1.2)
total = subtotal*vat
print(total)
```

However when I run this, the program spits nothing back.
Would appreciate any help on this as I am a newbie.

Thank you

Comment: I just ran your code and it works for me! One quick note though, in line 2, there's no need to wrap a `float()` function as `1.2` is automatically treated as a `float`

Comment: I don't use sublime, but your code worked fine for me. I stuck it in a file called `vat.py` and ran `python3 vat.py` via terminal and it did what you expect. As @ccl pointed out, the `float(1.2)` is not necessary.

Comment: It works fine for me

Comment: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/build-broken-python-3-input/44988

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue with Sublime Text 3's build system - can't get input from running program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254765/issue-with-sublime-text-3s-build-system-cant-get-input-from-running-program)

Comment: Can you explain how you chose the accepted answer?

Comment: Thanks @B1CL0PS
Running the code from the terminal worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code looks totally fine to me and running it behaved as I would expect:

```
$ python test.py
Enter the #: 10
12.0
```

Just guessing at a few ways it might not be working:

1. You are typing a number into the terminal after you run it, right? Calling `input` will pause the program until you type some string **and then press enter**. Are you doing that?
2. How are you running the code? You should run it from a terminal (1. open the terminal. 2. `cd` to your python file. 3. type `python3 myfile.py`.) If you saved this code in a python file and then ran it from your desktop environment (like by double clicking it in Windows) then it actually *will* work but the terminal window will close as soon as the program finishes so it will look like nothing happens. If you want this to work, just put `input("Press Enter to exit...")` as the final line of your program so it will wait and not close right away.

Also -- a few tips:

1. On line 1, you might want to handle the case where the user enters something that isn't a float -- if they type in some letters instead the program will crash with an exception. You can easily do this with a `try...except` block.
2. On line 2, `float(...)` is unnecessary because `1.2` is already a float.
3. Actually, though, when working with money it's a good idea to not use floats because of [floating point precision errors](https://floating-point-gui.de/). Instead, do your calculations as integer numbers of cents and then divide by 100 at the very end.

Comment: _How are you running the code?..._ From the OP:  _using sublime text and running my code though the sublime python system build_

Answer (score 0):

```
print("-" * 30)
print("Total amount: +VAT  £{:.2f}".format(round(total_amt*1.20, 2))) #shows receipt and VAT while also being rounded to 2 decimal places
print("-" * 30)
```