# python :- input from user issues in sublime

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I am writing python code in sublime (versions are latest). But when i try to input a value from user it just takes the value and does nothing.

**This is a simple example of that,**

```
name = input('Please enter your name: ')
print('Hello ' + name + '!' )
```

**output screen**

```
Please enter your name:  xyz

_ <-- after that cursor blinks here and nothing happens
```

Comment: [check out here](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/python-3-input-doesnt-work/34418/2)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19254765/3890632

Comment: If you want to execute an interactive program in Sublime (regardless of the language) you need to use a third party package. SublimeREPL and Terminus are examples of packages that can accomplish this for you.