# How to run function with variable of python in sublime

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I write a program in python as following:

```
def describe_pet(animal_type, pet_name):
    print("\n I have a" + animal_type + ".")
    print("My" + animal_type + "'s name is " + pet_name.title() + ".")
```

It runs smoothly in sublime with ctrl+B, but I don't know how to input variable "animal type" or "pet_name"
in sublime

Comment: You have to [call your function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130958/what-does-it-mean-to-call-a-function-in-python).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublime text currently doesn't allow user input. See this forum [post](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/python-input/34272). You can develop a custom build to add this functionality as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19297613/12602208), or you can install packages, which may make this possible. The last solution would be to use another IDE, such as VS Code.

Comment: This isn't true - see the duplicate. You can create custom build systems in Sublime that enable input, without needing SublimeREPL or other plugins.

Comment: @MattDMo Thanks for the comment! I edited my question to include custom builds as a solution and linked your answer.