# Why main method in java has to be (String. []args)?

Tags: java

I am confused on why main method on java has to be:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

My code is

```
public class MergeSorted 
{
    public static void main (int[] nums1, int m, int[] nums2, int n) 
    {
       ----
    }
}
```

Will executing >>java MergeSorted [2,4,5,0,0,0],3,[1,3],2; help?

Comment: The code is fine. Do you actually submit any inputs to the script?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't send input to running program in Sublime Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254765/cant-send-input-to-running-program-in-sublime-text)

Comment: @Trusha_Patel Please ask a new question if you have one, instead of changing the question.

Answer (score 3):

In Java the main method gets noticed by these exact method signature. The `String[] args` are the arguments the program started with. So when you compile your program, goto the command line execute your program you can put parameters behind the "start command"

For example

```
java -jar x.jar --myflag
                ^ args...
```

Then your String array is going to contain "--myflag", you can process those arguments to get the information that you want from it..

Answer (score 1):

You have to have it as you will run the program as a command line application. It it is javax application would be requiring a main method.

MergeSort.java

```java
public class MergeSort {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // get input via input stream
      mergeSort(...); // call method
   }

   public static void mergeSort(int[] nums1, int m, int[] nums2, int n) {
      // logic here
   }
}
```