# Unable to change Python 2.7 to Python 3.8 on Sublime and VS code

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, visual-studio, sublimetext3

I have been trying to change my python interpreter on sublime text and VS code and no matter what I do, both of them refuse to change. It always picks the default Python 2.7 version.

On sublime, I tried to create a new build tool, added the path to Python3 but nothing is working.

[image: Sublime Text Image]

And on, VS code, even if I select Python3 from the drop-down menu, it doesn't change anything.

[image: Visual Studio Image]

Answer (score 1):

I changed the system's default python interpreter from 2.7 to 3.9 and set the path on bash profile. It fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Sublime, but for VS Code, there looks to be [quite a few things to verify](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments):

1. Check your User Settings on whether you've set up a default interpreter for your applications
2. Are you using Window 10 WSL? Then you might want to check out [issue 3227 for vscode-remote-release](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/3227) where the comment was:

> So I was having this same exact issue until I read [this article](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl-tutorial) on a wsl tutorial. In there it says we should have "Remote - WSL" extension installed (already did). In the bottom left corner "Remote - WSL" installs a status button that has the "greater than" and "less than" symbols displayed. If you click that button and tell VSCode to open up in the remote WSL distro environment it fixed my issue where vscode was unable to find an interpreter for python.

Comment: The images show a Mac, so I don't think WSL applies here

Answer (score 0):

For Sublime, you need to hit <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> with your script pane focused in order to use your new `python3.sublime-build` build system.

It looks like you are running your script within Terminus, which is fine, but you need to use the `python3` command when running it from the command line, even if that command line is within Sublime.

Please check out [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19297613/1426065) on how to make a Python build system that accepts user input, as the Sublime "console" doesn't allow you to interact with your program. Since you already have Terminus installed, I'd recommend going down to the bottom of the answer and using the Terminus build system. That way, you won't have to deal with Terminal windows opening every time you run a build.

Answer (score 0):

The terminal window uses your `PATH`, not the IDE settings, so manually typing out `python --version` isn't testing anything except the `PATH` variable

In order for the terminal to use the "correct" python binary you've specified, it would need to give the absolute path to it, which I believe using Command+B (using the build options) in Sublime would do. Similarly, you can use the Run/Debug Configurations in VSCode.

Or you can modify your `~/.zshrc` to fix your PATH, for example installing `pyenv` to change the entire system Python version, or the one for the current folder

Comment: I changed the system's default python interpreter from 2.7 to 3.9 and set the path on bash profile. It fixed the issue for me.