# Sublime Text 3 error : [WinError2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c++, environment-variables, g++, sublimetext3

Now I know this has been asked several times before, but all the instances of this question I could find pertained to python. However, this issue affects me even when I try to run a c++ program.
Earlier today I was re-arranging some of my files (including ones that had sublime text).
My sublime text started acting up and the menu was completely gone.
I re-installed it and it seemed fine but whenever I tried to run a cpp (or any other) file it gave the error

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[shell_cmd: g++ "C:\Users\user\Desktop\INOI22\dynamic programming\lis.cpp" -o "C:\Users\user\Desktop\INOI22\dynamic programming/lis"]
[dir: C:\Users\user\Desktop\INOI22\dynamic programming]
[path:  C:\Windows\System32; C:\Windows; C:\Users\user\Desktop\Appdata\Local;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\user\Desktop\MinGW\bin;c:\users\user\desktop\inoi22\mingw\bin; c:\windows\system32; c:\windows; c:\users\user\appdata\local]
[Finished]
```

I have tried reinstalling it twice since, same error every time.

I also tried messing around with my environment variables, which I think might be causing this.

Currently my `%PATH%` variable is set to

```
C:\Windows\System32; C:\Windows; 
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Appdata\Local;C:\Windows\system32;
C:\Windows;
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Users\user\Desktop\MinGW\bin
```

[image]

Comment: I can't spot the error you're referring in the title? Please note that sublime is just a text editor, that allows you to run a compiler through shell macros. You should try to compile and run your stuff directly from the command line.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I use a custom build system that allows me to open up command line via CTRl+B sublime text and run it more conveniently. Same issue persists there

Comment: `C:\Users\user\Desktop\INOI22\dynamic programming` could be your problem. In `c` or `c++` its best to never use a space in a path.

Comment: @drescherjm unfortunately that did not fix the issue :(

Comment: @red24 please share the complete output of the error panel and what your `sublime-build` file looks like; without comparing what it's trying to do with what actually happens or the error that you're seeing, it's impossible to tell for sure where the problem is.

Comment: @OdatNurd 
[WinError2 The system cannot find the specified files]
[shell_cmd: g++ "C:\Users\user\Desktop\INOI22\dynamic programming\lis.cpp" -o "C:\Users\user\Desktop\INOI22\dynamic programming/lis"]
[dir: C:\Users\user\Desktop\INOI22\dynamic programming]
[path:  C:\Windows\System32; C:\Windows; C:\Users\user\Desktop\Appdata\Local;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\user\Desktop\MinGW\bin;c:\users\user\desktop\inoi22\mingw\bin; c:\windows\system32; c:\windows; c:\users\user\appdata\local]
[Finished]

Comment: for testing purposes im using a default build of c++ in sublime and my program is just printing 0

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using the `C++ Single File` build system that comes with Sublime Text:

```json
{
    "shell_cmd": "g++ \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\"",
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c++",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "shell_cmd": "g++ \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" && \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\""
        }
    ]
}
```

Unfortunately, it's Unix/Linux-centric in that the executables generated are named just by the first part of the file name. So, if you're compiling `test.cpp`, the executable will just be called `test`, with no extension. On Windows, however, executables need to have the `.exe` extension (generally speaking, there are exceptions) to run properly. We'll take care of this by modifying the build system.

In Sublime, select **`Tools → Build System → New Build System…`** all the way at the bottom. A template that looks like this will come up:

```json
{
    "shell_cmd": "make"
}
```

Erase all of that, and add this instead:

```json
{
    "shell_cmd": "g++ \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}.exe\"",
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c++",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "shell_cmd": "g++ \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}.exe\" && \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}.exe\""
        }
    ]
}
```

You'll notice that I replace the `\"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\"` parts with `\"${file_path}/${file_base_name}.exe\"`. The last thing to do is save the new build system. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> (or **`File → Save`**) and the save dialog should automatically be in your `Packages/User` folder, where `Packages` is the one opened when selecting **`Preferences → Browse Packages…`**. On Windows, it is either

- Regular Install: `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages` or `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text\Packages`
- Portable Install: `InstallationFolder\Sublime Text 3\Data\Packages` `InstallationFolder\Sublime Text\Data\Packages`

The exact path depends on version and whether or not you upgraded from Sublime Text 3. Name the file something like `C++ Single File (Windows).sublime-build`. It should now show up in the build system selection menu and in the Command Palette.

Now, you should be able to compile properly (assuming proper code) and run the executable without issues. Please keep in mind that Sublime does not support interactive user entry (`scanf` in C, `cin` in C++) with regular build systems, so you'll either need to [use a different custom build system or use `Terminus`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19297613/1426065) (the recommended solution).

Answer (score 0):

1.First I checked if my file.cpp , inputf.in and outputf.out are in the same folder .
2.Then , I checked the build system file by going to Preferences > Browse Packages > buildsysfile.sublime-build and I noticed that in the file I have specified outputf.in for seeing output but I had opened outputf.out , so i specified outputf.out there and saved .

This worked for me .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an **antivirus** like McAfee or any other, you may also face this issue. Try to disable real-time scanning, then run your code.

Also, i am using the following build file for **c++**

```
{
"shell_cmd": "g++ \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}.exe\"",
"file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"selector": "source.c++",

"variants":
[
    {
        "name": "Run",
        "shell_cmd": "g++ \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}.exe\" && \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}.exe\""
    }
]
}
```