# Sublime will not run any code within if and else statements

Tags: python, if-statement, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have tried reinstalling it and it still has this problem, in the following code i try to call the function within the if and else statement but it does not run the code. It does work in pycharm though, but i really would rather keep using sublime.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml

def jc ():
    url = ("https://jc.ne10.uol.com.br")

    keywords = ["assaltos","petrobras", "Gasolina", "etanol", "diesel", "gnv", "postos", "postos de combustíveis", "ANP", "Petrobras", "construção civil", "mercado imobiliário", "Habitação estradas", "infraestrutura", "obras públicas", "argentinos","Brasil"]


    response = requests.get(url)


    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")


    filtered_links = []
    for link in soup.find_all("a", href=True):
        for keyword in keywords:
            if keyword.lower() in link.text.lower() or keyword.lower() in link["href"].lower():
                filtered_links.append(link["href"])
                break

    Titles = []
    for title in soup.select("h1",class_="title"):
        for keyword in keywords:
            if keyword.lower() in title.text.lower():
                Titles.append(title.text)
     
    unique_links = list(set(filtered_links))


    for title in Titles:
        print("Titulo:")
        print(title)
    for link in unique_links:
            print("Link:")
            if (url == ("https://jc.ne10.uol.com.br//economia")):
                print("https://jc.ne10.uol.com.br/" + (link))
            else:
                print(link)

user_input = input("Do you want to execute the function? (yes/no): ").lower()

# Check user input and execute the function accordingly
if user_input == "yes":
    print(jc())
else:
    print("Function not executed.")
```

not even a code like whis will run, without any functions.

```
response = input("Do you want to execute the function?")
if response == 'yes':
    print('hello')
else:
    print("goodbye")
```

Comment: I suggest you remove the long example and keep only the short one. ([MRE])

Comment: Does the code run at all? Is the `else` part executed instead or nothing is?

Comment: Allegedly, Sublime Text [does not allow input](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/python-3-input-doesnt-work/34418/2) when running a program. When I run your simple Python script (the shorter one) it prompts for input but does not accept input and simply hangs there. Arguably, this disqualifies Sublime Text as a usable script runner, if true. You might need to override its default build system for Python as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254765/cant-send-input-to-running-program-in-sublime-text).

Comment: It runs on every IDE but not sublime so i guess it is not viable right? Damn that sucks, i really liked the minimalistic style. And yeah, the else is not executed too, nothing is.

Comment: Use `Thonny` as a beginner, it’s a light way IDE written in python. You get it from (https://thonny.org/ ) via pip.

Comment: Or configure ST for interactive builds per [instructional video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etIJMVIvVgg).

Answer (score 0):

Use Sublime 4 with Anaconda package, you can find an description here, https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Anaconda.
This will change your sublime to an IDE.

I made a test with my **Sublime4** and if you add `print("user_input")` it does what you expect:

[image]

I use `Terminus` from https://github.com/randy3k/Terminus

[image]

You can also find a smart solution with package `SublimeREPL` here from
[Samiul__Abid](https://www.reddit.com/r/SublimeText/comments/nzc2dr/how_to_be_able_to_activate_user_inputs_into/). Works directly without the extra print().